# Getting "video player is too small" using youtube iframe API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I'm using the youtube iframe API to embed several clips in my pages. Some of the clips (not all) sometimes show a "player too small" message when I try to play the clips. The players are much larger than the 200x200 required minimum size. Any idea why this could be happening?

**EDIT:**
Solved. Apparently, if I set the quality of the clip before loading it, that message is no longer being displayed...

Comment: Do you have snippets which we can reproduce the situation?

Comment: In the following link you can find an example. It happens only after you click on an answer there (I'm generating the iframe on the fly in that case)
http://www.playbuzz.com/shayc/cover-versions-whos-track-is-this-originally